# Overwrite variables to a specific position in text file with R

Tags: r, text-files, overwrite

I am trying to "replace" variables in an existing text file (cf an excerpt below) with
my R script.
Variables are called var1 through to var6 and the values below need to be replced. The position of the variables within the text file is always the same.

```
*** BLOCK B: WATER FLOW INFORMATION ************************************
hTab1   hTabN
1e-006   10000
  M          H
  0          0
var1     var2     var3     var4     var5     var6
0.095     0.41     0.03     1.5     0.26     0.5
```

Someone got any ideas?
Kind Regards

Comment: My appologies: What I posted is stored in a .txt file. (amongst other things)
I want to open the .txt file and replace some of the values below the var1-var6
Any clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get with this solution, maybe someone else come with simpler.

1. read data using readLines to get a lisst of lines
2. use grepl to find index of the line contaings `var1`
3. extract values in a a vector using `strsplit` : xx
4. create a new list of vector , with new values and name it using xx : here new values are 1:6
5. use `gsubfn` to replace the old list.

Here my code

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(object='*** BLOCK B: WATER FLOW INFORMATION ************************************
  hTab1   hTabN
1e-006   10000
M          H
0          0
var1     var2     var3     var4     var5     var6
0.095     0.41     0.03     1.5     0.26     0.5 '))
## get the line with values
id <- which(grepl('var1',ll))
##

xx <-strsplit(gsub('[ ]+','|', ll[id+1]),'[|]')

## replace values
library(gsubfn)
vals <- 1:6
names(vals) <- xx[[1]]
ll[id+1] <- gsubfn("[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+",  as.list(vals), ll[id+1])

1] "*** BLOCK B: WATER FLOW INFORMATION ************************************"
[2] "  hTab1   hTabN"                                                         
[3] "1e-006   10000"                                                          
[4] "M          H"                                                            
[5] "0          0"                                                            
[6] "var1     var2     var3     var4     var5     var6"                       
[7] "1     2     3     4     5     6 "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it (basically the solution from agstudy)

```
library(gsubfn)
l  <- readLines("myfile.txt")
id1 <- which(grepl('var1',l))
x <-strsplit(gsub('[ ]+','|', l[id1+1]),'[|]')
vals1 <- c("",0.095, 0.41, 0.03,  1.5,0.26,999999)    # var values to be altered manually, i added ""
names(vals1) <- x[[1]]
l[id1+1] <- gsubfn("[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+",  as.list(vals1), l[id1+1])
writeLines(l, "myfile.txt")                           # overwrites the old myfile.txt
```

/cheers

Comment: if you look closely, I referenced you (!) and made small alterations (write command).
This is a little added information for further searchers.

Comment: correct. but as i explicitly asked for replacing smth in a text file, I completed the answer.